# position of prepositional phrase in a sentence

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases

Flood destroyed car in Thailand.
If I change this sentence into passive.

> Cars in Thailand were destroyed by flood.
>
> Cars were destroyed in Thailand by flood.

Which one is suitable? I prefer the first as I think the flood was in Thailand and noun phrase '' the cars in Thailand '' is suitable for this sense.

Comment: I think the salient interpretation is in  the former, "in Thailand" describes where the cars were. In the latter, it describes where the action took place.

Answer (score 1):

Since Thailand needs to be mentioned, this sounds like a news bulletin. In this case I would start with the country where the flood occurred.

> In Thailand, cars were destroyed by a flood.

I also added the indefinite article "a".